# Need a searchText highlighter in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am working in an application where I have used "UITextField" as SEARCHBOX. when the user enter the search text in uitextfield UiTableView with sections will display the result, but I need to highlight the text entered in the textfield in the tableview. I have used attributed text but it is only possible within a range. So please help me an idea for implementing the highlighter.

```
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: contactsList.familyName + contactsList.givenName, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "Catamaran", size: 14.0)!])
        if contactsList.familyName.count >= 4 {
            myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(location:0,length:4))
        }else {
            myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(location:0,length:2))
        }
        cell?.profileName.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Comment: add code what you have tried..

Comment: myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: firstname, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "Catamaran", size: 14.0)!])
                if firstname.count >= 4 {
                    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(location:0,length:4))
                }else {
                    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(location:0,length:2))
                }
                cell?.profileName.attributedText = myMutableString

Comment: hard to read here edit your question add code there apparently you will get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change foreground color but it just changes text color not background color. 
I don't know whether this is the right solution or not, but you can try something like this.

If I understand your problem correctly,
[highlihted textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bONu7.png)

Add a label globally

```
let label = UILabel()
```

Set label frame in viewDidLoad

```
label.frame.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: textfield.frame.size.height)// your settings width should be 10 or smaller
label.font = UIFont(name: "Halvetica", size: 14)
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Set textfield text color to textfield background color

```
textfield.textColor = UIColor.white
```

Add textFieldEditingChanged method like this:

```
  @IBAction func changed(_ sender: Any) {

    label.removeFromSuperview()


    label.text = textfield.text

    textfield.addSubview(label)
    label.sizeToFit()
}
```

Don't forget to set label and textfield fonts same. If you don't, textfield cursor may appear behind or front of label

**UPDATE:**
You should create attributed string with html

```
extension String {
var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8),
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
}// you can find several way to do this just google it
```

}

Data source:

```
var dataSource = ["foo","foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6"]
```

Create variable for found result indexes at range in data source strings

```
var indexes : [Int:Range<String.Index>] = [:]
```

cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let string = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.attributedText = string.html2AttributedString

    return cell
}
```

searchText editingChanged:

```
@IBAction func change(_ sender: UITextField) {
    indexes.removeAll()
    dataSource = ["foo","foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6"] // assign datasource again
    for i in 0..<dataSource.count {
        if let textRange = dataSource[i].range(of: textField.text!) {
            indexes[i] = textRange
        }
    }
    for (index,entry) in indexes {

        let highlighted = "<text style='background-color:#FFFF00';>\(dataSource[index][entry])</text>"
        dataSource[index].replaceSubrange(entry, with: highlighted)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You should change font and size in html after some searching.
[image: result]

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for u r answer buddy, but I need to highlight the letters or words in tableView which is being searched in a UITextfield

Comment: Updated, check this answer.